# subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get unique, at_least_one and total counts of a contract with sql. Below code is throwing an error:
**Scalar subquery produced more than one element**

```
#standardSQL
WITH estrato_contrato AS (SELECT ESTRATO, CONTRATO, count(*) AS count FROM `mytable` GROUP BY ESTRATO, CONTRATO)


SELECT ESTRATO, COUNT(DISTINCT CONTRATO) AS only_once_contract, sum(count) AS total,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONTRATO) FROM estrato_contrato WHERE count > 1 GROUP BY ESTRATO) AS at_least_one
FROM estrato_contrato
GROUP BY ESTRATO
```

Comment: run the subquery on its own to see what it returns.

Comment: it returns count of unique contracts for each estrato

Comment: But that sub-query is only allowed to return one single row. Do a LEFT JOIN instead of sub-query!

Comment: LEFT JOIN in  one table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to formulate the subquery uses a correlation clause:

```
SELECT ESTRATO, COUNT(DISTINCT CONTRATO) AS only_once_contract, sum(count) AS total,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ec2.CONTRATO)
        FROM estrato_contrato ec2
        WHERE ec2.count > 1
              ec2.ESTRATO = ec.ESTRATO
       ) AS at_least_one
FROM estrato_contrato ec
GROUP BY ESTRATO;
```

There may be other ways to write the query but this is the intention of your version.

Comment: It helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

WITH estrato_contrato AS (SELECT ESTRATO, CONTRATO, count(*) AS count FROM mytable GROUP BY ESTRATO, CONTRATO)

SELECT ESTRATO, COUNT(DISTINCT CONTRATO) AS only_once_contract, sum(count) AS total, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CONTRATO)>1 then 1 else 0 end as at_least_one
FROM estrato_contrato
GROUP BY ESTRATO

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Option with no sub-selects

```
#standardSQL
WITH estrato_contrato AS (
  SELECT ESTRATO, CONTRATO, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM  `mytable`  GROUP BY ESTRATO, CONTRATO
)
SELECT 
  ESTRATO, 
  COUNT(CONTRATO) AS only_once_contract, 
  SUM(COUNT) AS total,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_AGG(IF(COUNT > 1, CONTRATO, NULL) IGNORE NULLS)) AS at_least_one
FROM estrato_contrato ec
GROUP BY ESTRATO
```

And, finally most simple one is (note: you don't need to worry of distinct values in outer select because it is already taken care of in estrato_contrato

```
#standardSQL
WITH estrato_contrato AS (
  SELECT ESTRATO, CONTRATO, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM  `mytable` GROUP BY ESTRATO, CONTRATO
)
SELECT 
  ESTRATO, 
  COUNT(CONTRATO) AS only_once_contract, 
  SUM(COUNT) AS total,
  COUNTIF(COUNT > 1) AS at_least_one
FROM estrato_contrato ec
GROUP BY ESTRATO
```